# I cannot get my Filter in Javascript to work

Tags: javascript, filter

this is the first time I have attempted a filer method in JS on an array. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am getting undefined for checklist after the const beveragesChecklist (filter line) when I do console.log.  I do not know why. Also, is the last part (after the debugger line) necessary after the return line? I cannot find anywhere on line including MDN site that gives a full example of the entire function. Please help and thank you!

```
function filterChecklists() {
    $('.beverages_button').on('click', function(event) {
      //console.log('click')
      event.preventDefault()
      fetch(`/checklists.json`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(checklists => {
         $('#checklist_container').html('')
         //console.log(checklists)
         const beveragesChecklist = checklists.filter(checklist => {
           return checklist.item === 'beverages';
           //console.log(beveragesChecklist)
            //console.log(checklist)
            debugger;

           let newChecklist = new Checklist(checklist)
           let checklistHtml = newChecklist.newChecklistForm()
            $('#checklist_container').append(checklistHtml)
         });
       })
     })
 }
```

Comment: Nothing after the `return` statement would be executed - that immediately ends the function.

Comment: that is what I was thinking. However, I still am not getting a result. There are no errors in console, but there is no display of my beveragesChecklist and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to do something like this:

```
function filterChecklists() {
  $('.beverages_button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    fetch(`/checklists.json`)
    .then(resp => {
       resp.json()
         .filter(checklist => checklist.item === 'beverages')
         .map(checklist => new Checklist(checklist))
         .forEach(checklist => $('#checklist_container').html(checklist.newChecklistForm()));
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think about it this way:

```
const beveragesChecklist = checklists.filter(checklist => {
  return checklist.item === 'beverages';
}
```

Is "the same" as:

```
let tempArr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < checklists.length; i++) {
  let checklist = checklists[i];
  if(checklist.item === 'beverages') {
   tempArr.push(checklist);
  }
}
const beveragesChecklist = tempArr;
```

So in the end you will have in beveragesChecklist all the items from the checklists array that met the condition. After that you can use that result however you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works - thank you Twisting nether !

```
 function filterChecklists() {
    $('.beverages_button').on('click', function(event) {
      //console.log('click')
      event.preventDefault()
      fetch(`/checklists.json`)
      .then(resp => {
        resp.json()
      .then(checklists => {
         $('#checklist_container').html('')
         //console.log(checklists)
           const beveragesChecklist = checklists.filter(checklist => checklist.item === 'beverages')
         .map(checklist => new Checklist(checklist))
         .forEach(checklist => $('#checklist_container').html(checklist.newChecklistForm()));
         });
      });
    })
  }
```